# Não consigo dar echo em objetos

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema orientado a objetos com [php](/questions/tagged/php) e notei que o código a seguir não funciona:

```
<?php
include 'User.php';

$temp_user = new User();
$temp_user->set_name(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$temp_user->set_user_name(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
$temp_user->set_password(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));

//$local_name= $temp_user->get_name();

echo "<br>$temp_user->get_password()<br>"
?>
```

Mas o mesmo código sem enviar diretamente o metodo da classe funciona:

```
include 'User.php';

$temp_user = new User();


$temp_user->set_name(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$temp_user->set_user_name(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
$temp_user->set_password(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));

//$local_name= $temp_user->get_name();

$var1 = $temp_user->get_password();

echo "<br>$var1<br>"
 . "<br><br>"
 . "<br><br>";
?>
```

**O que pode estar errado?**

OBS: todos os meus métodos estão publicos

Comment: Tente colocar chaves no primeiro código: `{$temp_user->get_password()}`

Comment: No primeiro código. Ou faça assim: `echo "<br>".$temp_user->get_password()."<br>"`

Comment: Dentro do `echo`. Algo como `echo "<br>{$temp_user->get_password()}</br>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, 
o PHP não consegue compreender objetos dentro da string.

Uma solução: no primeiro código faça o seguinte:
echo "<br>".$temp_user->get_password()."<br>";

Irá funcionar.

Comment: Tem como explicar porque o código atual não funcionou e porque este funciona? Se fizer isso, por favor, faça editando a resposta, não nos comentários.